# Searching for String that is part of other strings

Tags: r, regex, substring, gsub, stringr

I am trying to extract street names in spanish. For example, AV stands for avenue. However, my data also has "Barrios" or areas of the city. There are some that contain the abbreviation of the string in their own name or the patient wrote down a note instead of their address, such as:
AV : LA NAVARRA
CL : SIN DATO LA NOMENCLATURA

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to only find "CL" where it is not in the middle of the word. I could not work it out with spacing because some of the data starts with the road name and others don't. Additionally, some people write the st. type and immediate address: CR78B which means I cannot eliminate those with spaces after.

Here is a data example to use:

**streetNames-**

```
LA NAVARRA

BARRIO VILLANUEVA CR 40 # 01-02

CR 32 # 92-00

SIN DATO LA NOMENCLATURA

CR4#89-00
```

I basically need it to extract to CR and not include those that don't apply. 
Right now, this is what I have:

**`str_extract(streetNames, "CR")`**

Very simple I know. Please let me know if you have any suggestions or if anything is unclear

I have tried the word boundaries \b, to no avail. Maybe I am using them wrong if anyone has any suggestions.

Here is my code:

A didn't fix the first columns and used paste because I wanted to keep it flexible and not waste time. If you think the solution is to do that manually, then I will do it
Here it is:

```
cr <- c("\\bCR","CRR","CRA","CARRERA","CARERA", "CRRA", "CARREA", "KRA", "KR", "CARRRA", "CARREEA", "CARREA", "CARRARA(?=\\d*.))")
cl <- c("\\bCL", "CALLE", "CLL", "CALL", "CLLE", "CAALE", "CC", "CAL", "CLE", "KL(?=\\d*.))")
tv <- c("\\bTRANSVERSAL", "TV(?=\\d*.))")
dg <- c("\\bDIAGONAL", "DG", "DIAG", "DIAGIONAL", "DIGONAL", "DIG(?=\\d*.))")
av <- c("\\bAVENIDA", "AV", "AVDA(?=\\d*.))")
via <- c("\\bVÍA", "VIA(?=\\d*.))")
------------------------------------

cr <- paste(cr, collapse = "(?=\\d*.)|\\b")
crS <- paste("(?:(?<= )K(?=[ \\d*])", cr, sep = "|")

cl <- paste(cl, collapse = "(?=\\d*.)|\\b")
clS <- paste("(?:(?<= )C(?=[ \\d*])", cl, sep = "|")

tv <- paste(tv, collapse = "(?=\\d*.)|\\b")
tvS <- paste("(?:(?<= )T(?=[ \\d*])", tv, sep = "|")

dg <- paste(dg, collapse = "(?=\\d*.)|\\b")
dgS <- paste("(?:(?<= )D(?=[ \\d*])", dg, sep = "|")

av <- paste(av, collapse = "(?=\\d*.)|\\b")
avS <- paste("(?:(?<= )A(?=[ \\d*])", av, sep = "|")

via <- paste(via, collapse = "(?=\\d*.)|\\b")
viaS <- paste("(?:(?<= )V(?=[ \\d*])", via, sep = "|")

all <- paste(c(crS, clS, tvS, dgS, avS, viaS), collapse = "|")
```

The all at the end will then be used with string extract to take out all the values that qualify.

Comment: Use regex word boundaries `\b` as such `\bAV\b`

Comment: Could you elaborate? When I put it between my strings it i did not work, everything just came out as NA

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes in [tag:r]

Comment: I don't get what you're asking for. Have you tried `grep('CR', addresses, value=T)`?

Comment: When I use \b it then eliminates those that might be CR4 because it thinks that is the whole word. I would need an option that would not count numbers as part of the word if it were to work :(

Comment: Grepl removes and I am simply trying to extract

Comment: Can you give an example to work on with the expected results?. Try giving 3 or four names and what you need to extract from them, and what you expect

Comment: In the street names you gave above, what do you expect as the results?

Comment: I want to extract the appropriate letters to then change them to the value I want. So originally I was using values of which I wanted the product to be C or CR and then later I change it so all would be CR.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you want to match `CR` which should not be in the middle of the word, but  there can be a digit after the `CR` which should not be selected.

If that is the case, you could use a word boundary at the start `\b` and use a positive lookahead `(?=` to assert that what comes after could be zero or more digits `\d*`

[`\bCR(?=\d*)`](https://regex101.com/r/t6j35m/1)

For example:

```
str_extract("CR4#89-00", "\\bCR(?=\\d*)")
```

[Test output](http://rextester.com/OWB45926)

Comment: I was forced to also change the search criteria to look for "C" representing "Calle". Now, it finds any word that starts with a C and change it to CL.

 The C's I would be looking for would not have anything before or after it (only spaces), unless it is a # sign or a digit. If it is too hard to include the "#" as an option, I think it could be fine without it. Thank you!

Comment: @Colin My answer is based on the data in the question. To match the C's that would not have anything before or after it (only spaces), unless it is a # sign or a digit, this might be an option:
[`(?:(?<= )C(?=[ \d#])|\bCR(?=\d*))`](https://regex101.com/r/YoYafo/1)

Comment: Sorry it took so long to answer, if I have not been able to try it out until now. For some reason, it does not pick up the letter at all. here is an example of the database:      C 73C 2C 07
VILLA RICA CAUCA
CR 36 #70
C 37 39-71
VEREDA EL CARMELITO
CR 28C #42C-55
C 12 A#23 C -35

Comment: @Colin If you add your string to the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/YoYafo/2) it does select the `C`. Can you be more specific what does not pick it up?

Comment: When I run it on my code, it changes those with a C in them to Cr no matter what. I am not sure why, I will keep trying.

Comment: Hi thefourth bird, basically I think the difference might be that you joined to two parts in parenthesis but I can't do that. In reality, I use a much longer list with different variations and I combine them using paste to make things simpler and save space. I was hoping to not make a hug vector with the regex, but I will try that and let you know what it looks like.

Comment: How can I share my code with you? It does not fit in the comments

Comment: You could add your code snippet or relevant code to your question with your expected result.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I put it up there if you want to check it out.

Comment: Hello @the fourth bird, I was wondering if you needed any more information or had any additional suggestions. Thanks!